# Is Joomla just slow, or can I speed it up somehow?

Tags: php, performance, joomla

I have Googled this issue for a good while now, but I can't find a single article that discusses the speed of Joomla rather than the loading speed of external resources like scripts and images. My Apache + PHP setup is performing very well - compression is enabled and I'm using a local virtual machine to run it. The problem is with Joomla on the server side, and I don't know how to track down the source of it.

A page on my local Joomla setup *always* takes between 2 and 3 seconds to load. According to the *Network* tab in Chrome Developer Tools, the browser waits for the HTML page for about 2 seconds, then loads all the external resources in about 0.3 seconds. This is the case for *every* page, even the administrator pages. This leads to very frustrating page-surfing, as every link click is followed by a pretty long wait. For illustration, here is a screenshot of the loading speed graph. The blue line is the HTML page:

[image: Illustration]

What is it about Joomla that can take 2 seconds of processing for *every* request? Is Joomla just this slow, or must something be wrong with my setup? If so, how do I debug it?

---

#### What I've tried

- I've created a PHP page completely separate from the Joomla setup and filled it with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` just to confirm that all PHP scripts aren't affected by the 2s delay. They aren't.
- I've written and executed a small PHP script that connects to the local MySQL server, both by "127.0.0.1" and "localhost", and prints out all the tables in the Joomla database. The script runs in just a fraction of a second, so the fault doesn't lay with DNS issues when connecting to the database.

---

#### Joomla profile information for loading the front page:

```
Application 0.000 seconds (+0.000); 0.81 MB (+0.807) - afterLoad
Application 0.217 seconds (+0.217); 2.29 MB (+1.479) - afterInitialise
Application 0.296 seconds (+0.079); 4.34 MB (+2.055) - afterRoute
Application 0.640 seconds (+0.345); 5.59 MB (+1.247) - afterDispatch
Application 0.705 seconds (+0.065); 5.85 MB (+0.266) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (Main Menu)
Application 0.774 seconds (+0.069); 5.91 MB (+0.053) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (Main Menu)
Application 0.774 seconds (+0.000); 5.90 MB (-0.009) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (All Front End Views)
Application 1.004 seconds (+0.229); 6.05 MB (+0.147) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (All Front End Views)
Application 1.004 seconds (+0.000); 6.03 MB (-0.016) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (User Menu)
Application 1.035 seconds (+0.032); 6.05 MB (+0.021) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (User Menu)
Application 1.036 seconds (+0.000); 6.04 MB (-0.010) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (A Deep Menu)
Application 1.058 seconds (+0.023); 6.06 MB (+0.017) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (A Deep Menu)
Application 1.059 seconds (+0.000); 6.05 MB (-0.010) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (This Site)
Application 1.092 seconds (+0.034); 6.06 MB (+0.014) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (This Site)
Application 1.092 seconds (+0.000); 6.05 MB (-0.013) - beforeRenderModule mod_login (Login Form)
Application 1.116 seconds (+0.024); 6.07 MB (+0.023) - afterRenderModule mod_login (Login Form)
Application 1.116 seconds (+0.000); 6.07 MB (-0.002) - beforeRenderModule mod_breadcrumbs (Breadcrumbs)
Application 1.143 seconds (+0.027); 6.09 MB (+0.021) - afterRenderModule mod_breadcrumbs (Breadcrumbs)
Application 1.143 seconds (+0.000); 6.09 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (Top)
Application 1.179 seconds (+0.035); 6.12 MB (+0.028) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (Top)
Application 1.179 seconds (+0.000); 6.10 MB (-0.012) - beforeRenderModule mod_search (Search)
Application 1.207 seconds (+0.028); 6.13 MB (+0.028) - afterRenderModule mod_search (Search)
Application 1.236 seconds (+0.029); 6.15 MB (+0.014) - afterRender
```

Notice that the "afterInitialise", "afterDispatch" and "afterRenderModule mod_menu (All Front End Views)" steps take almost a third of a second each. Each of those points run for longer than I would accept the whole script running. Any clues on how to reduce those?

<sub>I hope this question is specific enough that it won't be closed instantly. If there's anything I can do to make it more specific, please comment.</sub>

Comment: Do you have PHP APC or eAccelerator or some other PHP caching engine installed?

Comment: @BenD: I just installed PHP APC (`apt-get install php-apc`) and that effectively reduced the waiting time from 2 seconds to about 1.4 seconds. One would think that the small amount of processing involved in displaying a simple Joomla page would take only a 10th of that, even on a really slow machine. Got any pointers?

Comment: You might also go in a optimize your DB tables just to make sure. I would have expected the APC install to drop you below a second, but it may be that Joomla just has too much overhead. What are the stats of the server you're running on?

Comment: @BenD: It's a VMWare virtual machine. The host machine has an i7 3770k processor if that's relevant. I have visited multiple known Joomla sites and few of them even dip below 1000ms occasionally. I have installed WordPress on the same virtual machine, and the pages have between 100 and 250ms load time, so I've concluded that Joomla is just *slow*.

Comment: In my experience, having built about a dozen Joomla sites, it is pretty slow.  There's a bunch of stuff going on that most users simply don't need, you can obviously improve things by making sure images are compressed/optimised etc, not having too many modules on one screen etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

joomla is just slow (i expect to get marked down for this), but it is. I have tested with APC, eAccelerator and a couple of others with various versions of PHP and apache, even tried with nginx, both as a module and FastCGI.

it seems that joomla is just bloated now. personally, if your using it for simple CMS purposes, i would recommend wordpress for beginners, or drupal for more advanced users.

Comment: Joomla is only slow if you have old PHP and MySQL versions, along with a hench database full of thousands of articles and loads of extensions. I have developed multiple Joomla sites, all of them being rather fast

Comment: @Lodder: Define "rather fast". My quick speed tests was on a clean Joomla 3.0 installation on a virtual Debian machine, with PHP 5.3 and MySQL 14. I just installed Wordpress a few minutes ago to compare, and the default pages load in about 200ms, compared to Joomla which takes between 1300ms and 2100ms per page, presumably depending on the cache status. (I'm just talking about the waiting time for the main HTML file, not including any external resources.)

Comment: I'm not saying that that Joomla is faster than WP cause I know it not, however, you must remember than Joomla and WP serve different purposes. WP is for blogging, where as Joomla is far more flexible due to the amount of coded features and extensions available. My sites is on a shared server running PHP 5.3, MySQL 5.1.66, uses heavy extensions and a framework based template. Even then, it still loads in around 2secs which I deem extremely good. You take a look at some WP based websites that have lots of content such as http://css-tricks.com, speed test results come in at just over 4 seconds.

Comment: @Lodder, I agree. I have developed multiple Joomla sites and have found speed to be really good. I have a complex e-commerce site which loads a full page in 1.5s. The only things I found that slowed Joomla down are: my very sad little localhost laptop; my own sloppy coding. On a >proper< host with good coding, the latest version of Joomla (3.3.3) runs beautifully.

Comment: @JustPlainHigh, not trying to be offensive here or anything but... seriously, you think 1.5 seconds is a reasonable time for a page to load? 0.5 seconds is a reasonable time... not 1.5

Comment: Not offended, but I forgot to mention I don't have a high speed internet connection. Nothing gets to me in under a second. So maybe it is faster... *Wonders*

Answer (score 1):

I had better results enabling the different levelsof cache in the system options. If u use no cache it will be slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "levels of cache"? Can you point to any specific [PHP APC directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) or Joomla settings?

Comment: I mean in the joomla control panel. I had one site with disabled cache the page would load in many seconds. With cache enabled the loading time was lot less.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately none of the cache options made much of a difference. The best combination of options was "Conservative caching" with the "File" handler, which at most reduced the pages' load speed from 1.4 to 1.1 (on average) seconds. I wouldn't be satisfied before the load speed was below 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Sometimes if you have a module in joomla which load external content (for example RSS feeds or even libraries like jquery or Google API fonts etc) joomla first preload everything then it goes on. I don't think you will reach that fast result because depends on the various latency times of the different external sites.

Comment: First are you talking about a single article page or a category page or what? IF you are finding that a single article takes 2 seconds and you have no extra system plugins installed and are only using core modules i'd be really interested in looking at your site.  Overall the most common sources of slow pageload in J3 sites are:
1.Buggy system plugins --- make sure that you have error reporting on max to test whether you are getting strict errors.
2. Corrupted asset table usually caused by a botched migration and then 3. old mysql but i don't know what you mean by mysql 14

Answer (score 0):

It could be down to your Webhost ... Amazon AWS is a nightmare when comes to shared resources. On small  or even medium instances your CPU resources is shared and I usually get 50% of the resources "stolen" ... %st ... this makes the server load high and thus pages are extremely SLOW. You can forget about micro instances ... your server load is at constant 90% +

We're planning to move web hosts at the end of the year. Let's hope we can fix this issue.

Comment: Notice that I said "local virtual machine". There are no webhosts involved.

Answer (score 0):

Running joomla 2.5 on localhost (windows) i experienced times up to 8 sec on administrator tasks. Finally i had to disable some php extensions to improve performance.
ex. php_pdo_oci.dll , php_pdo_mysql.dll etc
Try to work with only the necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Joomla takes more time in cooking the resulting html when compared to wordpress. Why? because it provides you a powerful framework to take your website far more than just a blog.